# Using CSOM, get image url from PublishingRollupImage field

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I have use `var url=oListItem["PublishingRollupImage"];`

but it contain Img tag & I want only Image url.

I also use below code but it is not available in CSOM:

```
 ImageFieldValue imageUrl = oListItem["PublishingRollupImage"] as ImageFieldValue;
                if (imageUrl != null)
                {
                    item.imageUrl = imageUrl.ImageUrl;
                    item.imageWidth = imageUrl.Width.ToString();
                    item.imageHeight = imageUrl.Height.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: It gives Error:(ImageFieldValue)oListItem["PublishingRollupImage"] Cannot cast 'oListItem["PublishingRollupImage"]' (which has an actual type of 'string') to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.ImageFieldValue'

Comment: I understand now, you want to do it in CSOM! I tried to clarify the question for you. From what I know, the `ImageFieldValue` is not exposed in CSOM so you would have to use the first approach and then do som regex or string parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PublishingRollupImage` gives string value containing `<img .../>` tag.

So, as Robert mentioned in comments, you need to use Regex to extract the `src` value from the string.

You can use the sample code to extract the `src` value from the field.It will give the server relative url of the image.

```
ListItem targetListItem = list.GetItemById(8);                

context.Load(targetListItem, item => item["PublishingRollupImage"]);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//gives value containing img tag
var imageField = Convert.ToString(targetListItem["PublishingRollupImage"]);

//Regex to extract the src value from the img tag
string imageUrl = Regex.Match(imageField, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Below is the end result I got in a sample console application.

[image]

Regex reference - [Regular Expression to get the SRC of images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257359/regular-expression-to-get-the-src-of-images-in-c-sharp/4257450#4257450)

You need to add `System.Text.RegularExpressions` dll to your code to use regex.